# APEX 5.1.3 -- Clicking the Edit Button in the Report Page Shows a Form for Inserting a New Record

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using APEX 5.1.3 to build a new desktop web application. I created a pair of Report and Form pages, and then ran the application, entered the report page. The data in the table was shown correctly, and each row contained a pencil icon at the leftmost column -- all looking fine.

However, when I clicked on the pencil icon to enter the Form page, instead of showing the record and let the user update the record, all columns became blank. The Save button was not there, instead the Create button appeared. This became the same behavior as clicking the Create button in the report page. What did I do wrongly, and how could I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I can find the answer after clicking the APEX edit page here and there...

I go to the edit page of the Report Page, on the left side, under Content Body, select Attributes.

On the Right side, under Link, click Target.

A new window appears at the center. I found the page no. is correct, but the Set Items aren't. Hence I click on the ^ button to select the correct column on the left, and values on the right. Click OK and then Save and Run the page. The problem is then corrected.

The reason for the problem is that for whatever reason, my original version has a value item which does not exist at all. Hence the data can't be brought to the form page when the edit button is clicked in the report page.